# cannot do join in Linq properly

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am very new at Linq. I am trying to do Linq JOIN in my project but I cannot do it properly. No data comes out of the Linq statement.

Would you please give me a hint for below?

```
companyVM[0].brand_relations = (from cbr in db.AY_COMPANY_BRAND_RELATIONS
                                join c in db.AY_COMPANIES on cbr.COMPANY_ID equals c.ID                           
                                join b in db.AY_BRANDS on cbr.BRAND_ID equals b.ID
                                where cbr.COMPANY_ID == ID 
                                select b).ToList();
```

I am very sure that some rows must come from the DB. Am I doing a syntax error?

Comment: The first join, you join on `ID` and not (for example) `c.ID`. Is that a mistake?

Comment: No, ID comes as paramter

Comment: Then how do you expect to join in a table, if you don't reference any of the columns in it?

Comment: is there way to see the SQL generated from Linq?

Comment: You could trace the sql server, for instance, to see what sql is sent to it.

Comment: I cannot see it in the trace. The Profiler is on

Comment: Just replace companyVM[0].brand_relations = (from...).ToList() to var t = (from......).ToList() ... and see in the runtime if you are able to get any values for t, if it's not then surely the join condition is wrong , which means even if you execute the same query in sql server , you wont get any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first join doesn't use `c` at all. This:

```
join c in db.AY_COMPANIES on cbr.COMPANY_ID equals ID
```

should almost certainly be

```
join c in db.AY_COMPANIES on cbr.COMPANY_ID equals c.ID
```

(or whatever the ID should map to within `db.AY_COMPANIES`).

It's at least *surprising* that you don't use `c` anywhere else in the query, too.

Comment: I fixed that but that didnt solve my problem. Is there anythingelse I should check?

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ: Yes, you should look at what SQL is being executed, and then perform the same query manually, tweaking it to see what you get.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot catch it on Profiler

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ: You don't need to - you should be able to tell LINQ to SQL (or whatever - we can't tell from the query which provider you're using) to log the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
from cbr in db.AY_COMPANY_BRAND_RELATIONS
   join c in db.AY_COMPANIES on cbr.COMPANY_ID equals ID
```

that looks suspicious, may be it's like this

```
from cbr in db.AY_COMPANY_BRAND_RELATIONS
       join c in db.AY_COMPANIES on cbr.COMPANY_ID equals c.COMPANY_ID
```